# Radiant floor heating head unit turns off when turn lights on

Tags: electrical

My radiant floor heating head unit and the light switch are in the same box sharing power in lines split between the 2.    Whenever I turn the lights on in the room the floor heating head unit turns off and turns back on when the lights are turned off.  Also when the lights are off and the head unit is on the room lights will randomly flash on then off    [image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the electrical boxes involved? Also, how many amps is the circuit, how many watts does the radiant floor pull, and what type of lightbulbs are in the light fixture? (incandescent, CFL, LED?)

Comment: Thanks.  I will post a photo in the morning but it is on a 15 amp breaker and the radiant floor heater says it is 3 amps on amazon.  3 of the Light bulbs are led 1 is a old 60 watt Incadescent.   The way the electrical is set up is pretty basic  1 line in and the hot and neutral are each split to the wall switch and head unit

Comment: Your switch doesn't have a neutral wire. White is not neutral.

Comment: Can you provide a photo of the back of the switch?

Comment: Also, where does the wire in the silver braid go?

Comment: The top and bottom lines of the radiant floor head unit connect to the Silver wire that goes down to the radiant floor.   The white coming from the wall is the hot in this case and it powers a bathroom light fixture

Comment: Plain switches aren't supposed to have neutral wires. None of this makes sense.  It looks like someone just hooked random wires together until he found a combination that semi-worked.  That's how you create serious wiring hazards.  Also, the reason you have 1 incandescent is because putting in all LED broke the heating unit.  Power isn't supposed to work this way.

Comment: The bulbs are my doing.  I am switching everything to led, ran out and forgot about it until now.    The picture is sideways but the line on the top is the main line.   I think it is a switch loop because the white is the hot line.    What is the proper way to wire what’s there   Thanks for any help.  Just trying to fix what’s wrong in the old house I bought